# SVG Grid Rendering Chrome,Firefox,IE - Wrong Line Alignment - Blurred Lines

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

In order to create an SVG I am drawing several lines in SVG.
The issue is that It looks different in Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome: Last line not drawn
Firefox: Firts line not drawn

BTW: The internet explorer version looks blurred, but this is not the main issue.

So who is right now?

What am I doing wrong.

To give you some background information: I am drawing this grid usually dynamically from JavaScript. Do I have to write ugly hacks to deal with these different SVG browser rendering behaviors?
(I do not want to use any libraries but plain JavScript)

See this codepen.io here:
http://codepen.io/mjost/full/kuaFH

here is the code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" id="phoenix10_5" viewBox="0 0 960 768"> 
<defs>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
svg
{
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke-linecap: butt;
}
text
{
    alignment-baseline: auto;
}
]]>
</style>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="960" height="768" rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)"/>
<g>
<rect x="69" y="44" width="746" height="187" rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)"/>
<g>
<svg x="69" y="44" width="746" height="187" viewBox="0 0 746 187">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="746" height="187" style="fill: #FFFFFF"/>
    <g>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="746" y2="0"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="18" x2="746" y2="18"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="37" x2="746" y2="37"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="56" x2="746" y2="56"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="74" x2="746" y2="74"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="93" x2="746" y2="93"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="112" x2="746" y2="112"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="130" x2="746" y2="130"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="149" x2="746" y2="149"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="168" x2="746" y2="168"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="187" x2="746" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="74" y1="0" x2="74" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="149" y1="0" x2="149" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="223" y1="0" x2="223" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="298" y1="0" x2="298" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="373" y1="0" x2="373" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="447" y1="0" x2="447" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="522" y1="0" x2="522" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="596" y1="0" x2="596" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="671" y1="0" x2="671" y2="187"/>
        <line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="746" y1="0" x2="746" y2="187"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewBox is "0 0 960 768" so that's what you can see. When you draw

```
<line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="746" y2="0"/>
```

You are saying that you want a stroke 1 pixel wide from y=-0.5 to y=0.5 as 1/2 the stroke is on each side of the line. However all of the stroke from -0.5 to 0 is clipped because of the viewBox so you're asking to see a crisp edged stroke 1/2 a pixel wide which isn't really possible for a UA to do. Sometimes a UA will display it inside the viewBox and you'll see it and sometimes it will draw it outside the viewBox and then you won't.

If you want to use strokes with crispEdges it's best to draw them at 0.5 units e.g.

```
<line stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" x1="0.5" y1="0.5" x2="746" y2="0.5"/>
```

Theres a [fuller explanation here](http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines)

Comment: Why has anybody said: "hey why not making complicated to draw a simple line". And why did they write the specs after this. I can understand that this is a vector format, but it is some kind of wired to talk about half pixels.

Comment: Read the link. You can either display fills nicely or you can do strokes nicely, it's impossible to do both.